# Relation between heat energy and resistance

Tags: resistance, heat

There is a simple question that why is the heating element of an electric heater hotter than the wire connecting it to the switch. It's ans is that the resistance of the element is greater but H=I²Rt and H=(V²/R)t by using any of these formulae if we will calculate the heat produced (for the same voltage) it tells us that heat produced in wire will be more.  I'm a 10th class student so please don't use complex language and words.

Comment: It would help to actually *ask a question*.  Also, proofread what you wrote and correct it.  Your teachers may let you slide and not take points off, but the real world doesn't work that way.  Sloppiness indicates lack of respect to your readers.  Most of the time they won't tell you.  They'll just think to themselves *"what an asshole"*, then go on to give someone else the great opportunity, that extra higher mark for good effort, hire them for a job, etc.

Comment: Sorry sir I edited it for a grammatical mistakes.  Next time while asking a question I will keep it in mind. Thank you

Comment: No, you haven't edited anything.  Edits are tracked here.  We can all see when you made the last edit, and most of us can see the whole edit history.  I didn't downvote before because I was giving you a chance to fix things on you own.  Now you get a -1 for lying.  This isn't school where you can get away with nonsense like *my dog ate my homework*.

Comment: Closing due to disrespectful sloppiness, then lying about having attempted to fix it.

Comment: Sir in the last line I first wrote 'please don't use complex words' which seemed very odd of a 10th class student. Secondly I wrote formulas instead of formulae. I corrected these two and don't know why isn't it showing it here. And sir I never lie.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Was the edit in the first 5 minutes perhaps? Those don't get tracked.

Comment: @Mast: I pointed out the issue well past the first 5 minutes.  In any case, the sloppiness is *still* there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wire carries the same current as the heater (because they are connected in series), but has a much lower R, so by \$I^2R\$ generates less heat.

The series connection of heater and wire means that the incoming 240v is split between them. In the case of a nominally 10A heater, the resistance will be 24ohms. If the wire has a resistance of 0.024ohms (reasonable), then the 10A through the wire will result in a voltage drop of 0.24v, and so 2.4 watts generated in the wire. This will leave the wire so cool you'd barely notice it. The remaining 239.76 volts across the heater will give you 2397.6w rather than 2.4kW.

Comment: Let's take the resistance given by the wire is half the resistance give by the heater element. The voltage is constant. Then by V=IR we can say that if R becomes R/2 the current is going to be 2I. Then putting these in H=I²Rt.    H'=(2I)²(R/2)t. Solving this we get H'=2I²Rt. By this we can say that the heat produced in wire is more than that in the heating element.

Comment: The current through the wire and the heater is always equal, they are in series

Comment: You obviously don't understand what 'in series' means. If the wire carries current from the switch to the heater, then the current will be the same in the wire and the heater. Let's take a more reasonable assumption that the wire has 1/1000th the resistance of the heater. Say 240v supply, 24ohm heater, 0.024 ohm wire, roughly 10A flowing (as the heater resistance dominates the sum). Power in heater 10*10*24 = 2.4kW, power in wire =10*10*0.024 = 2.4W (so don't run the wire under a carpet, it could get too hot).

Comment: I got it. But let us take two circuits both with 240V power supply. One with a resistance of 24ohm and other with resistance of 0.024ohm. Current flowing through the circuit will be 10A and 10000A respectively (from V=IR). Now if we calculate the heat produced it will be more in the circuit with less resistance.

Comment: But you have two distinct circuits.  If you put the 24 ohm resistor (simulating a heater element) and the 0.024 resistor (simulating the connecting wires) in series, then the current will be the same in both and the power dissipated is then proportional to the resistance.  Thus the 24 ohm resistor will dissipate 1000 times the power dissipated in the 0.024 ohm resistor. This is why the connecting wires don't heat up.

Comment: If you apply 240v to a 0.024ohm price of wire, then of course 10kA will flow, and it will get very hot, very quickly, or would if the fuse didn't blow. But that's not what we have when connect a heater to the switch with a wire. They are in series, and the heater limits the current to 10A. There is 239.75v dropped across the heater, and 0.25v dropped across the wire, because the same current flows in each, and Ohm's Law says the voltage drop is IR.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you sortof have the right idea, but you need to be clearer about power into the resistor and its resulting temperature.  In this context, "heat" is too vague a term.

The *power* electrically dumped into a resistor is:

P = I<sup>2</sup>R = V<sup>2</sup>/R

where P is the power, I the current, V the EMF, and R the resistance.  In MKS units, no additional conversion factors are required:

W = A<sup>2</sup>Ω = V<sup>2</sup>/Ω

In this case, W is the power in Watts, A the current in Amps, Ω the resistance in Ohms, and V the EMF in Volts.

That's the power going into the resistor.  The only thing a resistor can do with that power is turn it into heat.  However, heat power is not immediately temperature.

Let's say you have a fixed voltage or current applied to a fixed resistor.  When the circuit is first turned on, the power into the resistor will cause its temperature to rise at a steady rate.  However, as the temperature of the resistor increases, it starts losing heat power to the air around it.  As that happens, it heats up more slowly because the total power into the resistor (electrical power in minus heat power lost to the air) goes down.  The hotter it gets, the slower it heats up more.

After you wait long enough, the system will be close enough to *equilibrium* or *steady state* so that you can't notice it changing anymore.  At that point, the heat power going out of the resistor to the air matches the electrical power going in.  The net power into the resistor is 0, so it stays at the same temperature.

By the way, this slowing movement to a steady state comes up often in physics and other sciences, and is called a *exponential decay*.  In theory, the system never gets to steady state because that would take infinite time.  In practice, eventually it gets close enough so that you don't care, can't measure the difference, or other sources of noise dominate so that the value is bouncing up and down little bits, but a lot more than the remaining distance to steady state.

Comment: Not related to this answer, but your site linked to in your profile is blocked on Firefox due to 'potentially unwanted programs.' You should be able to file a reconsideration to get it removed. I didn't see a contact on the site.

Comment: @Jarrod: Yes, this is a ongoing issue with some malware detection software getting false positives.  Apparently something in our low level libraries matches a dumb pattern they are looking for.  I have sent test cases, asked Google to "rescan" the site while explaining the situation, etc, but to no avail.  *"We don't care.  We don't have to.  We're Google."*

Comment: Ah, yes, Google can be fun like that. Good luck!